# Filter out some UTF-8 characters with Regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex, unicode, utf-8

I am quite new to regular expressions and UTF-8. So there are some characters, mainly symbols which I need to elmininate. So I need a Regex where I can check if a String contains some specific characters. What is the easiest way to do this?

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

There in the table the first two rows for example and the DEL symbol.

Reason is, that some of these characters Users type in are not printable so it will lead to problems when exporting the input to a pdf for example.

EDIT:

I want to use the Regex.test() method from Javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

So I have a String, which contains one character I don't want and when I pass it to the test() method it will return false.

Comment: Could you provide an example input and desired output? Have you tried anything?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/280712/2401386) might help you.

Comment: `[\u0001-\u00FF]` matches the Unicode characters with the codes 0x1 to 0xFF if thats what your looking for (which is not very clear)

Comment: @Niitaku I updated it.